# destroy iDangerous Swiper if window is resized to a bigger resolution or call it when resized to a smaller resolution

Tags: jquery, swiper.js

i'm using [iDangerous Swiper](http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/) for my website in lower resolutions. here is how i'm calling it:

```
var resolution = 670;
if ($(window).width() < resolution) {
var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
    mode:'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    grabCursor: true,
    paginationClickable: true
});
```

so, when you access it in a desktop browser, the swiper will not be called. what i want to do is to "turn it on" if the user resizes the window to a size smaller than `resolution` or destroy it if the user accesses it in a small window size and then resizes it to bigger than `resolution`. i tried this, but it didn't work:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() < resolution) {
        if(typeof(mySwiper) === "undefined" ) {
            var mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({
                mode:'horizontal',
                loop: true,
                grabCursor: true,
                paginationClickable: true
            });
        }
    } else {
        if (typeof(mySwiper) !== "undefined" ) {
            mySwiper.destroy();
        }
    }
});
```

two undesirable things happen:

1. if the user is in a small resolution and resizes it to a resolution that still calls the swiper, it restarts the swiper.
2. if the user is in a small resolution and resizes it to a bigger resolution, it is not destroyed.

i thing my problem is the `typeof`. i don't know much how variables work when they are called like this: `$('.swiper-container').swiper()`.

how do i "uncall" swiper and how not call it if it was already called?

Answer (score 18):

My solution:

```
var mySwiper = undefined;
function initSwiper() {
    var screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if(screenWidth < 992 && mySwiper == undefined) {            
        mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {            
            spaceBetween: 0,
            freeMode: true
        });
    } else if (screenWidth > 991 && mySwiper != undefined) {
        mySwiper.destroy();
        mySwiper = undefined;
        jQuery('.swiper-wrapper').removeAttr('style');
        jQuery('.swiper-slide').removeAttr('style');            
    }        
}

//Swiper plugin initialization
initSwiper();

//Swiper plugin initialization on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    initSwiper();        
});
```

And it worx! :)

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and found that as soon as the width was beyond my max width, mySwiper was again `undefined` and therefore the `if(typeof)` statement always returned `false`.

I found another hybrid solution with the `fired[]` array below and also realized that while the `destroy()` method may be executing in my example, the swiper itself had added a style attribute to the wrapper and slide DIVs which was persisting after the destroy method was called and only went away with a page refresh. After I added the `removeAttr()` method calls on the two DIVs, everything worked as expected.

Your mileage may vary.

```
$(window).on('resize', function ()
{
    if ($(this).width() <= 383 && !fired[0])
    {
        fired[0] = true;
        fired[1] = false;

        mySwiper = $('.swiper-container').swiper({ mode: 'horizontal', loop: false, wrapperClass: 'swiper-wrapper', slideClass: 'swiper-slide' });
    }
    else if ($(this).width() >= 384 && !fired[1])
    {
        fired[0] = false;
        fired[1] = true;

        mySwiper.destroy();

        $('.swiper-wrapper').removeAttr('style');
        $('.swiper-slide').removeAttr('style');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and took a similar solution:

**init function:**

```
var mySwiper;
```

**my resize function:**

```
if(jQuery(window).width() < 672) {
    if (typeof mySwiper == 'undefined') {
        mySwiper = new Swiper('#myId', {
            calculateHeight: true
        });
    }
} else {
    if (typeof mySwiper != 'undefined') {
        // destroy and delete swiper object
        mySwiper.destroy();
        mySwiper = undefined;

        // reset styling for wrapper and slides
        jQuery('.swiper-wrapper').removeAttr('style');
        jQuery('.swiper-slide').removeAttr('style');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having problems destroying and initialising Swiper on demand try calling reInit() with a slight delay.

define Swiper reference on page load

```
var mySwiper;
```

Start Swiper

```
// Set Slider 
        mySwiper = new Swiper ('.swiper-container', {loop: true }); 
 // Run Update after 500ms
        setTimeout(function() { mySwiper.reInit(); },500);
```

Destory Swiper

```
  if (typeof mySwiper != 'undefined') {  
    mySwiper.destroy();
    mySwiper = undefined;
  }
```

If your updating markup through ajax ensure you empty the container first. i.e:

```
 if (typeof mySwiper != 'undefined') {  
   mySwiper.destroy();
   mySwiper = undefined;
 }    
 $('#container-with-swiper-markup').html("");
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I know I'm late to the party, but I had similar issues and ended up with a solution that works solid.

**The story**: Swiper needs to run on desktop, but not on mobile (small screens) and should be able to change between them on resize.

**Requirements**: In my example, I'm using jQuery, Swiper and Modernizr (for media queries, as window width etc is unreliable).

**JavaScript**:

```
/*! Michael Pumo - Web Development. http://michaelpumo.com */

(function($, Modernizr) {

    'use strict';

    var state = {

        swiper: false,

        setOrGetDevice: function(device) {

            if (typeof(device) === 'undefined') {
                var mq = Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 768px)') ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
                device = mq;
            }

            return device;

        },

        device: function() {

            return state.setOrGetDevice();

        }

    };

    var cache = {

        $window: $(window),
        $swiper: $('.swiper-container'),
        $swiperElements: $('.swiper-container, .swiper-wrapper, .swiper-slide')

    };

    var swiper;

    var app = {

        init: function() {

            app.swiper();

        },

        swiper: function() {

            if(state.device() === 'desktop' && !state.swiper) {

                swiper = cache.$swiper.swiper({
                    parallax: false,
                    initialSlide: 0,
                    direction: 'horizontal',
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: 3000,
                    speed: 1000
                });

                state.swiper = true;

            } else if(state.device() === 'mobile' && state.swiper) {

                swiper.destroy();
                swiper = undefined;
                cache.$swiperElements.removeAttr('style');

                state.swiper = false;

            }

        }

    };

    $(function() {
        app.init();
    });

    cache.$window.on('resize', function() {

        var mq = Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 768px)') ? 'desktop' : 'mobile';
        state.setOrGetDevice(mq);
        app.init();

    });

})(window.jQuery, window.Modernizr);
```

As well as checking the 'device' (in other words, mobile size or desktop size), it checks against a flag I set in `state.swiper`. As this is a mobile-first approach, this flag is initially set to `false`.

I know that my explanation is brief, but this works 100% and has the benefit of not initializing Swiper at every stage of the resize, thanks to the flag.

The **HTML** would just be the standard **HTML** that Swiper requires, so that's what you should use if you're going with this solution.

Hope it can be of some help to someone.

Thanks,
Mikey.

Answer (score 0):

I have a better solution which has given by the [http://idangero.us](http://idangero.us/swiper/api/#.WcDhirIjGiM)

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'vertical',
    loop: true
})
if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    swiper.detachEvents();
}
```